# Novel about a normal teenage girl (?African American) who suddenly shrinks and has to fight to survive

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I read this book in the mid 80's in Australia. I'm pretty sure it was American in origin and about a teenage girl of colour. She was suddenly transported to another world, a desert world... and had to fight to survive. She returned to normality after a while but would be returned to that alternate reality every so often. She felt that she was shrinking when she changed and hid a shard of glass in a fold of her palm, which would become a knife when she became tiny again.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.